# Cannot start a process in c#

Tags: c#

I've written this code to start a process:

```
var proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("{0} {1}", inputFilePath, outputFilePath);
proc.StartInfo.FileName = @Settings.GetImageMagickConvertPath();
proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
proc.Start();
```

This works perfectly locally. But when I put this code on a remote machine, this code no longer works (Error is "Access is denied" when trying to start the proc). So, I've added the credentials I use to connect using RDC (user/pass) in order to start the process:

```
proc.StartInfo.UserName = "user";

System.Security.SecureString secret = new System.Security.SecureString();

foreach (char c in "pass")
    secret.AppendChar(c);

proc.StartInfo.Password = secret;
```

but I still receive the same error...

Do you guys see anything which can be fixed for this issue?

Comment: Which operating system(s) are involved?

Comment: do you have to pass an username password perhaps the remote machine requires a service account user/pw try passing Credentials with username password perhaps it expects domain/user + Password

Comment: Dump the entire Access Denied exception to disk and see what the details are. My guess is this is an NTFS ACL issue. Is this from within an ASP.NET / WCF process? If so, check your Application Pool identity and Impersonation settings.

Comment: Using the credentials you already used for the RDC session won't help.  Dig up the admin of that machine and have him give the rights you need.  We can't help with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it's solved now.

Basically I had two issues:

1. The path to the process to start was incorrect (instead of `folder/program.exe` I put by mistake `folder/` and I received "Access is denied" which made my life a nightmare (started to look for rights, account etc). Would have been nice if Microsoft have been improved this error like "The path to the process is wrong").
2. I had to run it as a Local Service (app pool) instead of App Pool Identity. (and no need for Start Info credentials)

Operating system involved: Windows 2008 Server R1)